# Assigning a value treated differently

Tags: c

I have this snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main() {
    int x = 10/0;
    printf("%d", x);
    getch();
}
```

The above output is `10`.

But if I run this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main() {
    int x = 10/2;
    printf("%d", x);
    getch();
}
```

The output is `5`.
Why?

I'm using `TurboC++` compiler for `Windows 7` using `DosBox`.

Also, if I'm doing like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(){
    int  x=10;
    x=x/0;    //now it would not compile and gives error
}
```

Comment: What compiler do you use (and what version)?

Comment: surprised the first one did not throw a div by 0 exception

Comment: Your first code listing gives me a `Floating point exception`, See sharptooth's answer below.

Comment: I guess this question should be migrated to arithmetics.stackexchange.com, if it exists.

Comment: You do realize that `/` is division right?

Comment: @nightcracker: i'm using `turbo c++` for `Windows 7` using `dosbox`

Comment: @Nick: it was almost surely "evaluated" at compile-time, thus the lack of exception. UB allows this sort of "optimization". :-)

Comment: @nightcracker: i'd updated my post. Please see it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 10/0 prints 10

Division by zero is [Undefined Behaviour](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior) (*). Anything can happen. If you're lucky, the computer will print some very unexpected thing forcing you to correct the programming error; if you're unlucky the error goes unnoticed for a long time.

> 10/2 prints 5

This is correct. `10` divided by `2` is `5`.

(*) The [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says:

> 6.5.5/5
>   ...
>   ... if the value of the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Dividing by zero is undefined behavior, so any result is permitted - it may crash or the compiler might refuse to compile that code (Visual C++ 10 does so). Dividing 10 by 5 yields 2 as you would normally expect.

Comment: Refusing to compile is not valid behavior unless the compiler can prove that the expression will always be evaluated. For instance, `1?1:1/0` is perfectly valid. Perhaps more interesting is `if (first_counterexample_to_riemann_hypothesis()) 1/0;`

Answer (score 2):

Because in basic arithmetic `10/2=5`.

Comment: @Mohammad Faisal it is purely meaningless to divide a number by zero, in your case some compilers will complain, others will ignore the basic mistake as punishment.

Comment: that's horrible. do I work for the compiler or the compiler works for me?